# Página Home se renderiza dos veces en angular 11 con router-outlet

Tags: angular11

Estoy teniendo el problema que la página de home se está renderizando dos veces; sé por qué: estoy usando la etiqueta `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` en el *app.component.html* pero no sé cómo solucionarlo.
Tengo un `ngIf` para la página de login porque no deseo que se muestre el header de la página. Para mi app he creado componentes por separado: header, footer, login, register form.

***app.component.html***
`<app-header *ngIf="hiHead"></app-header>`

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
`<app-footer></<app-footer>`

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'cdls-app';
  hiHead: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // on route change to '/login', set the variable showHead to false
      router.events.forEach((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          if (event['url'] == '/login') {
            this.hiHead = false;
          } else {
            console.log("NU")
            this.hiHead = true;
          }
        }
      });
    }
}

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

***app-routing.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterformComponent } from './registerform/registerform.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'registro', component: RegisterformComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: 
    [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Por otra parte, bienvenido/a a [es.so] Jorge, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Intenté mejorar la redacción en tu pregunta, de todas maneras: ¿ _sabes el por qué_ del error o _no sabes_?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, sé como se origina, pero no se como solucionarlo.